# Customizing Wordpress (Genesis) Themes

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

I'm trying to achieve something simple on the paper but that results to be hard due to the lack of support from Studiopress. What I'm trying to do is to change how a post summary is rendered by altering the CSS, so far I'm testing using firebug and changing the look "on the fly" to understant if it is possible or not. The theme that I'm trying to customize is this one:

http://demo.studiopress.com/lifestyle/

I want to make the middle widget (post #2 and #3) to look different (I'll suppress post #4 in widget settings) with the text under the image and not lateral, to make you an example of what I want to achieve, please refer to this other theme, which has the layout I need but not the "look":

http://demo.studiopress.com/magazine/

The middle widget area (travel) has the layout that I want, I've so far latered the CSS using firebug to make a bigger image, align the text correctly and change the overall look, so far so good. What I'm unable to do is to push the text under the image, I tried to work with these settings:

```
clear: left;
float: left;
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong or missing a part of the CSS. For instance if you look the bottom left/right widgets they are rendered as I want to do with the middle widget, I tried to compare the code but was unable to understand and modify appropriately.

**edit**: here is a sample of what I've achieved using firebug, for the text below changing the class to 'alignnone' from 'alignleft' resolved, yet I have to understand how this class is assigned to the element since i don't see an 'alignleft' in the front-page.php file.

[image: Sample Using Firebug only]

**edit 2**: so to update and clarify the homepage of this theme is widgetized and the loop is suppressed. Obviously I'm editing the code of the child theme, not the framework. I have figured out a few things about how the theme and framework works, I'll provide a temp url once I upload a test website.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide code. No one is going to pay and DL a premium theme in order to help you track this down. (Also, you don't REALLY need to know. You should be adding your changes in a child theme or additional CSS/LESS/WHATEVER file, not editing the core files of an off-the-shelf plugin.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all --- Those aren't widgets. They are posts in a loop. You won't need to "suppress" Post #4. IF you just set only three posts to be "Featured", it'll work fine.

(I'm wondering if you have actually DLed and installed the theme or if you are just fiddling around with the demo...)

Next --- To make the text sit below the image you do not need to add CSS, but rather cancel or remove some. Specifically, you need to get rid of `float:left;` on the anchor tag that contains the image. You want `float: none;`. The hard part is targeting the `<a>` elements you want and not any others.